# Erro ao chamar uma função do firebase com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo um site web utilizando o firebase. Estou bem no começo ainda mas ja enfrentei problemas. O login está indo normal, mas o cadastro não.
O erro -> "Uncaught TypeError: firebase.auth(...).createUserEmailAndPassword is not a function"
OBS: Os códigos auth() são da documentação do firebase.

Obrigado desde já!!

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    
    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "none";

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user != null){

      var email_id = user.email;
      var email_verificado = user.emailVerified;
      document.getElementById("usuario_nome").innerHTML = "Bem vindo! : " + email_id + " Veficação: " + email_verificado;

    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.

    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";

  }
});

function login(){

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("campo_email").value;
  var userSenha = document.getElementById("campo_senha").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userSenha).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Erro: " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}

function cadastro_usuario(){

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("campo_email").value;
  var userSenha = document.getElementById("campo_senha").value;

  firebase.auth().createUserEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userSenha).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Erro: " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input, button {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.main-div, .loggedin-div {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.main-div input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
}

.main-div input:focus {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

.main-div button, .loggedin-div button {
  background: #5d8ffc;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #5d8ffc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
}

.main-div button:hover, .loggedin-div button:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #5d8ffc;
  border: 1px solid #5d8ffc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Firebase Login</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="campo_email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" id="campo_senha" />

    <button onclick="login()">Logar</button>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="cadastro_usuario()">Criar nova conta</button>
  </div>

  <div id="user_div" class="home-div">
    <h3>Bem vindo!</h3>
    <p id="usuario_nome">Logado!</p>
    <button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
  </div>




<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: E qual é o erro que te retorna?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: firebase.auth(...).createUserEmailAndPassword is not a function, esse erro.

Comment: Você falhou no nome da função. A função chama-se `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: Cara, de certo, valeu demais!!! Peguei ontem o código da documentação oficial e tava dando erro, depois peguei de um vídeo e nada, to sem entender até agora, valeu mesmo!!!!